# saving document via services with Angular 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, web-services

Hi I am working at a angular 7 app with asp.net mvc.

And I am trying to save uploaded documents to database.

this is the method for saving the data:

```
export class EditDiplomaComponent extends AfwComponent implements OnInit {
    resources: DiplomasWijzigenResourcesModel;
    private readonly apiDiploma: 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
    readonly resourceKeys = DiplomasWijzigenResourcesModel.keys;
    buttons: ImmutableArrayType<ButtonModel>;
    protected readonly formName = FormNamesModel.diplomaForm;
    formModel: AfwFormService;
    documentList?: DocumentListModel;
    documentListCompoment: DocumentListComponent;
    diplomaFormKeysModel: DiplomaFormKeysModel;
    protected baseDocumentsUrl: string;
    teacher: TeacherModel;


    constructor(
        private readonly http: AfwHttp,
        readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        readonly textResourceService: TextResourceService,
        private readonly formService: FormService,
        private readonly multiFileUploadControlFactory: MultiFileUploadControlFactory,
        private readonly feedbackService: FeedbackStoreService,
        private readonly router: Router,


    ) {
        super(textResourceService, route);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.baseDocumentsUrl = `api/register/teachers/current/diploma/${this.teacher.guid}/documents?fileName=`;
        const defaultModel = diplomaFormModel(this.multiFileUploadControlFactory);

        this.formModel = this.formService.createModel<DiplomaFormModel, DiplomasWijzigenResourcesModel>(
            defaultModel, { qualificationTerms: null, diplomasUpload: this.multiFileUploadControlFactory.createEmptyDefaultValues() }, this.resources
        );

        const saveBtn = new ActionButtonModel({ resourceKey: this.resourceKeys.opslaanKnop, isSubmit: true });
        const cancelBtn = new CancelLinkButtonModel();
        this.buttons = ImmutableArrayType.Create([saveBtn, cancelBtn]);
    }

    diplomaDataSubmitted($event: AfwFormService) {

        // const formModel = $event;
        if (this.allowSubmitAgain && this.formModel.form.valid) {

            const obs = this.saveDiploma(true, this.resources.opslaanSpinnerTekst).pipe(map(() => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(RoutesRegisterModel.pathnameMyRegisterRouteDiplomas).then(() => {
                    this.feedbackService.addSuccessMessage (
                        {
                            feedbackPortalKey: FeedbackPortalsModel.mainFeedback,
                            message: { key: 'succesvolWijziging', value: this.resources.succesvolWijziging },
                        });
                });
            }))
            this.submitAllowed(obs);
        }
    }

    saveDiploma(competenceStatement: boolean, spinnerMessage: string): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.post(`${this.apiDiploma}`,
            competenceStatement,
            spinnerMessage);
    }
}
```

and this is the Diploma controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = IdentityRoles.Teacher)]
    [RoutePrefix("api/register/teachers/current/diploma")]
    public sealed class DiplomaController : ApiControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDiplomaProcess _diplomaProcess;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public DiplomaController(IDiplomaProcess diplomaProcess)
        {
            _diplomaProcess = diplomaProcess;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the diploma record for the current teacher.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="competenceStatement">Has agreed to the competence statement?</param>
        [Route("")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateDiploma(bool competenceStatement)
        {
            _diplomaProcess.CreateDiploma(competenceStatement);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete the diploma record for the current teacher.
        /// </summary>
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("")]
        public void DeleteDiploma()
        {
            _diplomaProcess.DeleteDiploma();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the diploma documents of the current teacher.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The DocumentListDto with the diploma documents.</returns>
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public DiplomaDto GetDiplomas()
        {
            return _diplomaProcess.GetDiplomas();
        }
}
```

But when I debug the code I see that on this line:

```
 return this.http.post(`${this.apiDiploma}`,
```

apDiploma is undefined. And I am using a Observable.

But I have the idee that you have to subscribe it. But how to subscribe the method?

Thank you

thank you. 
but at this line:  return this.http.post(`${this.apiDiploma}`,

I see the correct `url: "api/register/teachers/current/diploma"`

this is the output:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<DiplomaDto xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VLR.BackEnd.Dto.Teacher">
<Documents xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/VLR.BackEnd.Dto.Document">
<d2p1:Documents/>
<d2p1:DocumentsInQueue>-2147483648</d2p1:DocumentsInQueue>
<d2p1:IsSucceeded>true</d2p1:IsSucceeded>
</Documents>
<HasAgreedToCompetenceStatement>false</HasAgreedToCompetenceStatement>
</DiplomaDto>
```

But if debug the backend(controller)

then I see it doesn't this this method:

```
[Route("")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateDiploma(bool competenceStatement)
        {
            _diplomaProcess.CreateDiploma(competenceStatement);
        }
```

Comment: can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to define it as a type of string and assign it a value

change that line to

```
private readonly apiDiploma: string = 'api/register/teachers/current/diploma';
```

Comment: I get method not allowed

Comment: And I I get this error: {"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}